# Generate angular model properties by view, when view fields are empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, mode

I have controller like this:

```
function ($scope) {
    $scope.Package = {};

    $scope.CreatePackage = function () {
        console.log($scope.Package);
    };
}
```

and view like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Package.Name" />

<input type="number" ng-model="Package.Price" min="0" step="0.5" />

<button ng-click="CreatePackage()">Create New Package</button>
```

So, when I click this button not typing package name and price, I want my model to be:

```
{ Name: null, Price: null }
```

or

```
{ Name: '', Price: '' }
```

by default.

How can I make it automatically? is there any angular option to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the Name and Price attributes in your $scope.Package object initially. Binding the empty string will result in {Name: "", Price: ""} being the $scope.Package object inside your CreatePackage function.

```
$scope.Package = {
    Name:'',
    Price:''
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No, I want automatically, If I'll have there 20 properties it's not a good solution to write all of them manually

Comment: Not the best solution, it must do angular himself, not me.. I am interested is there any setting for example GenerateModelPropertiesByView: true, do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I don't know of any flag that will configure this to work the way that you wish. Another suggestion is to use something like:
    ng-init="Package.Price =''"
in every input field along with the ng-model

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.Package = {};
    $scope.CreatePackage = function() {
      
      if (!$scope.Package.Name && !$scope.Package.Price) {
        $scope.Package = {
          Name: '',
          Preis: ''
        };
      }
      console.log($scope.Package);
    };
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="Package.Name" />

  <input type="number" ng-model="Package.Price" min="0" step="0.5" />

  <button ng-click="CreatePackage()">Create New Package</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Herr is a plnkr [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wSxO1bogRyQrBjn15DPJ?p=preview)

Comment: I see, I don't know of any automatic solution.